# How can I concatenate a space using CATX function?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to form a line concatenating numbers and strings, but separated by a space.

I tried it in 5 ways, but it didn't give the desired result.

```
%LET lim1 = 113;
%LET lim2 = 166;
```

**Test 1:**

```
%LET linha = %SYSFUNC(CATS(De,&lim1,a,&lim2,clientes));
%PUT &linha;
```

**Out 1:**

```
De113a166clientes
```

**Test 2:**

```
%LET linha = %SYSFUNC(CATS('De ',&lim1,' a ',&lim2,' clientes'));
%PUT &linha;
```

**Out 2 (Error):**

```
30         %LET linha = %SYSFUNC(CATS('De ',&lim1,' a ',&lim2,' clientes'));
NOTE: Line generated by the macro function "SYSFUNC".
30          'De '113' a '166' clientes'
            _____   _____
            49      49
NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release.  Inserting white space 
             between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is recommended.
```

**Test 3:**

```
%LET linha = %SYSFUNC(CATX(' ','De ',&lim1,' a ',&lim2,' clientes'));
%PUT &linha;
```

**Out 3 (Error):**

```
29         %LET linha = %SYSFUNC(CATX(' ','De ',&lim1,' a ',&lim2,' clientes'));
NOTE: Line generated by the macro function "SYSFUNC".
29          'De '' '113' '' a '' '166' '' clientes'
            ________   ___________
            49         49
NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release.  Inserting white space 
             between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is recommended.
```

**Test 4:**

```
%LET linha = %SYSFUNC(CATX(' ',De,&lim1,a,&lim2,clientes));
%PUT &linha;
```

**Out 4 (Error):**

```
NOTE: Line generated by the macro function "SYSFUNC".
29          De' '113' 'a' '166' 'clientes
              ___   ___ ___   ___
              49    49  49    49
NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release.  Inserting white space 
             between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is recommended.
```

**Test 5:**

```
%LET linha = %SYSFUNC(CATX(*,De,&lim1,a,&lim2,clientes));
%PUT &linha;
```

**Out 5:**

```
De*113*a*166*clientes
```

Test 5 is as close as I need, but I need to replace * with a blank space.

**I need:** `De 113 a 166 clientes`

Unfortunately, I was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macro you don't need to use `CAT` for assembling a source code text.

Just resolve the macro variables in the context desired.

```
%LET lim1 = 113;
%LET lim2 = 166;
%LET linha = De &lim1 a &lim2 clientes;
%PUT &=linha;
----- LOG -----
LINHA=De 113 a 166 clientes
```

If using a macro variable value in the DATA step context of a quoted string or string value computation the resolution should be within double quotes of a string literal (*unless the macro value is already literally double quoted text*)

```
data have;
  input (part1-part3) ($);
datalines;
De a clientes
Si o consumer
Mr A Sky
;
%LET lim1 = 113;
%LET lim2 = 166;

data want;
  set have;
  result = catx(' ', part1, "&lim1", part2, "&lim2", part3);
  put result=;
run;
----- LOG -----
result=De 113 a 166 clientes
result=Si 113 o 166 consumer
result=Mr 113 A 166 Sky
```

Comment: It's unbelievable.